# Why does qdel comman return 'Unknown Job Id'

Tags: queue, centos, pbs, torque

**OS Version**

CentOS release 4.6 (Final) Kernel \r on an \m 2.6.9-100.ELsmp

**Problem**

When I run qdel i get the following error:

qdel: Unknown Job Id 20432.scyld.localdomain

**Information**

Output of qstat -n

```
head0.localdomain: Req'd Req'd Elap Job ID Username Queue Jobname
SessID NDS TSK Memory Time S Time

20432.head0.localdom gilg standard pc-iw-1 32729 1 128 -- 72:00 R 00:23 n39/5+n39/4+n39/3+n39/2+n39/1+n39/0
```

**Content of '/var/spool/torque/server_name'**

scyld.localdomain

**Question**

Why do I get the error?

Comment: Are scyld.localdomain and head0.localdomain the same machine?

Comment: What is the output of qstat -f